# Using CSS selectors to access specific table rows with selenium

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors

If I have the following HTML:

```
<tbody id="items">
<tr><td>Item 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item 4</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item 5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item 6</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

How would I use CSS selectors with Selenium to access Item 4(or really any item I wanted)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use nth-child selector:

```
#items tr:nth-child(4) {color:#F00;}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/7ow15mv2/1/

But no idea if it works with Selenium.

But according to docs it should.

> Currently the css selector locator supports all css1, css2 and css3 selectors except namespace in css3, some pseudo classes(:nth-of-type, :nth-last-of-type, :first-of-type, :last-of-type, :only-of-type, :visited, :hover, :active, :focus, :indeterminate) and pseudo elements(::first-line, ::first-letter, ::selection, ::before, ::after).

Comment: I haven't explored this, but in CSS isn't the `:nth-child()` selector zero-based? (My understanding is that the fourth row would be `:nth:child(3)`, though I could very definitely be completely wrong.)

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo "The index of the first child of an element is 1".

Comment: For the 4th column in the 5th row: document.querySelector("tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(4)")

Answer (score 2):

you can try this for searching by any inner text

```
css=td:contains('Item 4')
```

found this helpful: http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified/

Comment: where did you find ':contains' documented? it's not on the link you provided, nor does it work when I try it in the browser console, says it's not a valid selector.  Is this something that was around for a bit and then removed from CSS later?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to select by content ("Item 4")? By Position (the 4st row)? Or is `<tr id="foo">` and selecting
    tr#foo>td
an option?

Comment: position only without adding any extra HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
selenium.getText("css=table>tbody[id=items]>tr:nth-child(3)>td(3)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use xpath to find it in a number of different ways but the easiest is:

```
//td[text()='Item 4']
```